# How is it working : a specific while-loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
int main(){ 
char s;
    while(s!='\n'){
        scanf("%c",&s);
        if(s==' ')continue;
        else printf("%c",s);
    }
}
```

input:Stack over flow

output:Stackoverflow

what i expected:
SSttaacckkoovveerrfflloooww

I don't understand how this works.

Comment: It is undefined behavior, since `s` is not initialized. Beside that it seems that the loop just scans the input char by char and skips the spaces. You should explain why you expect that output.

Comment: Are you seeing a local echo?

Comment: *Buffering*, I'd wager. Output to `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is by default *line buffered* meaning it will not actually write to the console unless the buffer becomes full or there's a newline. Try to explicitly [flushing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) `stdout`.

Comment: because i print char.

Comment: well how can I reach this buffer

Answer (score 3):

```
- You have a while loop with the condition that s is not an enter character.
- You read a character from keyboard
- You test if the character is space.
- If true (the character is space) you continue reading another character
```

- If false (the character is not space) you print it on the screen (only that one character printed once)
- Nowhere in your code is there a line that prints twice the character you stored in s 
  E.g.      else printf("%c%c",s,s);